# Save result of the foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have developed foreach function for the following script

```
function kali($src, $key, $pengali)
{
    echo $pengali . ' x ' . $src . ' = ' . $pengali * $src . '<br/>';
}

$tampil = mysql_query(" SELECT DISTINCT term FROM `term` order by term  ");

while ($t = mysql_fetch_array($tampil)) {
    $term    = $t[term];
    $array   = array();
    $tampil2 = mysql_query(" select term, id_document, wdt from wdt where term = '$term' order by id_document  ");

    while ($t = mysql_fetch_array($tampil2)) {
        $term        = $t[term];
        $id_document = $t[id_document];
        $wdt         = $t[wdt];
        $wdt_r       = round($wdt, 2);
        $array[]     = $wdt_r;
    }

    foreach ($array AS $item => $value) {
        $temporary = array_shift($array);
        array_walk($array, 'kali', $value);
    }
}
```

I would like to save the result of multiplication that have been calculated in foreach function, `id_document` and term to the database.

Can I have a little help here?

Comment: Have your tried the **[INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html)** query?

Comment: Sidenote: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and your database queries are vulnerable to SQL injection. Switch to MySQLi / PDO and use prepared statements.

Comment: `kali` function has `$key` parameter which is not used; probably use `array_map` instead of `array_walk`. `mysql` library is outdated, consider using PDO (has iterators, no more `mysql_fetch_array`), SQL query on SQL query within PHP-code - use SQL JOIN instead. Second `while` is not clear, shouldn't it be limited to one iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run a query to insert data into database after you finish calculations:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name (id_document, term) VALUES ($id_document, $term)");
```

Let me know how it goes